# How to update php file using shell script

Tags: input, ssh

I want to update backup.php file with below details using shell script

```
$source_server_ip = ""; 
$cpanel_account = ""; 
$cpanel_password = "";
```

can someone please guide me how to ask below questions to user and update details in backup.php file ?

```
echo "Enter hostname: '$hostname'"
echo "Enter cPanel username: '$user'"
echo "Enter password: '$pass'"
```

I tried below code but got an error

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Your hostname: "
read hostname
echo "Your username:"
read user 
echo "$source_server_ip = "$hostname;"" >> backup.php
echo "$cpanel_account = ""$user"";  >> backup.php
```

Thanks

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By this way, you can try this

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter hostname: " hostname
read -p "Enter cPanel username: " user
read -p "Enter password: " pass

if [ -f "backup.php" ]
then
    rm backup.php
fi
echo "\$source_server_ip = \"$hostname\";" >> "backup.php"
echo "\$cpanel_account = \"$user\"; " >> "backup.php"
echo "\$cpanel_password = \"$pass\"; " >> "backup.php"
```

The built-in `read` command stops the script and waits for the user to type something from the keyboard. `-p` (prompt) is a shorthand feature that combines the `printf` and `read` statements. read displays a short message before waiting for the user to respond.

Comment: perfect ! Thanks much !

Comment: Can I ask one more help ? 

In case I want to add results as new line on number 4,5,6 . How can I do that ?

Comment: What kind of results?

Comment: echo "\$source_server_ip = \"$hostname\";" >> "backup.php"
echo "\$cpanel_account = \"$user\"; " >> "backup.php"
echo "\$cpanel_password = \"$pass\"; " >> "backup.php"

This line I want to add on in line number 4,5,6

Comment: is there way to get this one using sed ?